# correct header to download an mp4 file

Tags: php, header

Here i am testing with header functions which will allow me to download a mp4 file from browser.I have a file which is 94 megabyte in size.But when i click the download button i get a file which is only 273 kilobyte long.What might be the reason behind this situation and how i can solve this ?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['mymp4'])){
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_POST['mymp4'].'"');
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>' method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' value='Design Patterns for JavaScript Web Apps -- JavaScript Confer.mp4' name='mymp4'>
  <input type='submit' value='download mp4' />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("path/to/mp4"));
readfile("path/to/mp4");
```

Comment: worked..but why this worked.can you explain a bit about it?

Comment: For output file to browser you have use method readfile() and add headers that you needed. You can read more here about readfile method http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php